# redirect all subdomains with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have some unused subdomains and I would like to redirect them to my homepage.

I have found this .htaccess code

```
# redirect all subdomains
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/ [L,R]
```

It redirects when you call the exact subdomain, for example: **test.example.com**

But it does not work if you call anything else, for example: **test.example.com/meh**

It's possibile to redirect any URL in these subdmoains to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
# redirect all subdomains
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}`at the end of target will add previous URI to new target.

Comment: Thanks bur unfortunately it does not work. If you call  http://test.example.com/something it does not redirect to the main domain, it return a "subdomain" 404 error insted

Comment: Test is a new browser or completely clear browser cache then and enter `http://test.example.com/something` in browser. Assuming `test.example.com` is also pointing to same directory as `www.example.com`.